# Two browsers are opening automatically in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following is my code. One browser opens blank and another opens google.
I am using the latest version of chrome driver. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Trials {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Can you check via Task Manager if there's another instance of chromedriver running? Try closing all the instances of chromedriver, and then re-run your code

Comment: Check if you got an antivirus installed and that is interrupting in the browser start-up process.

Comment: I tried closing all instances of chromedriver but it still launches two browsers.